# Comparing two files, if string exists in file 1, print 2 and if not print 1

Tags: awk, text-processing

I have two files which I would like to compare. If string exists in file 1 (which only has one column), I would like to print a 2 next to it. If it only exists in file 2, I would like to print a 1 next to it. I want to keep all entries of file 2.

File 1:

```
5131885
5751191
```

File 2:

```
5131885 1000019 -0.013936 0.0069218 -0.0048443 -0.0053688 0.0074161
5751191 1000046 -0.015001 0.0015263 0.00039903 0.0017072 -0.0021732
1668460 1000081 0.026323 0.0068929 0.0048965 0.0077047 0.0061728
```

File 3 (desired output):

```
5131885 2 1000019 -0.013936 0.0069218 -0.0048443 -0.0053688 0.0074161
5751191 2 1000046 -0.015001 0.0015263 0.00039903 0.0017072 -0.0021732
1668460 1 1000081 0.026323 0.0068929 0.0048965 0.0077047 0.0061728
```

I tried to do it with awk, but I was not successful.
I reached this point:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$1]=$1;next} ($1 in arr){print $0,arr[$1]}' file2 file1 > file3
```

But it does not add an extra column.

Comment: There are other issues as well, but you certainly want to swap the order of the arguments: process `file1` first, and then `file2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$0];next} {$1=$1 OFS ($1 in arr?2:1)} 1' file1 file2
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '              ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{           ##Checking condition if FNR==NR which will be TRUE when file1 is being read.
  arr[$0]          ##Creating arr with index of current line value here.
  next             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  $1=($1 in arr)?$1 OFS 2:$1 OFS 1 ##Checking if $1 from file2 is present in arr then add 2 to it else add 1 to it.
}
1                  ##Printing current edited/non-edited line here.
' file1 file2      ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

***OR*** a small variant of above solution as suggested by @Kaz in comments try following:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$0];next} $1=$1 OFS ($1 in arr?2:1)' file1 file2
```

Comment: This is good!  Now, we could just have a `print` in the first action instead of adding the `1`. On the other hand, if you want to code golf it, you could just  drop the braces from the second action. `FNR==NR{arr[$0];next} $1=($1 in arr)?$1 OFS 2:$1 OFS 1`.  The assignment itself gives you the true value to trigger the print action.

Comment: @Kaz, Sure, thanks for nice suggestion, added this solution also in my answer, cheers.

Comment: Did I hear code golf? `NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$1=$1 OFS ($1 in a)+1`

Comment: Always look for common code to factor out of expressions. `$1 = ($1 in arr)?$1 OFS 2:$1 OFS 1` should be abbreviated to `$1 = $1 OFS ($1 in arr ? 2 : 1)`. IMHO using the result of that action as a condition to cause awk to print the current line just unnecessarily obfuscates the code and causes people reading it to wonder why you care about that condition rather than just printing unconditionally and look for cases where the condition would be false.

Comment: @JamesBrown, that's really cool trick you have used, thanks for sharing, cheers.

Comment: @EdMorton, Thank you sir, I have edited my answers now.

Answer (score 0):

Invert file1 and file2: Memorization of file1

Extract first field (k).

Remove first field (sub).

Detect k in memorized file1 for affect n (1 or 2).

print k, n and the rest of file2 line (without k).

```sh
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$1]=$1;next} {k=$1; sub(/^[^ ]+ /, ""); n=1} (k in arr){n=2} {print k " " n " " $0}' file1 file2
```